# Selenium firefox driver can't send numpad keys

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I want to send numpad keys to an input using selenium firefox driver. I have this code working on the Chrome driver :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;


private void sendKey(WebElement webElement) {
  webElement.sendKeys(Keys.NUMPAD0);
}
```

But in firefox, nothing is sent to the web element. Why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to send the keys with JS, or the most easiest way which probably is going to work:

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).clear();
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).sendKeys("What you want");
```

Or with JS executor would be:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)webDriver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementByXpath('XPATH').setAttribute('value', 'What you want')");
```